# Mongodb indexes by grouped fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, database

I've been doing the Mongo DB university course and started to look more at our application indexes; we have a collction that has a common query using the following fields:

_id:string, stats(schema).created_by:string, list(schema).user_id:string, deleted:false

Schema example:

```
var listSchema = schema({
    user_id: {type: String, trim: true},
    email: {type: String, trim: true}
}, {_id: false, versionKey: false});    

var modelSchema = schema({
   name: {type: String, trim: true, required: true},
   stats: {
          created_by: String,
          updated_at: {type: Date, default: new Date()},
   },
   deleted: {type: Boolean, default: false},
   list: [listSchema],
   other....
})
```

The most common query looks like this:

```
var queryParams = {
        _id: projectId,
        $and: [
            {
                $or: [
                    {'stats.created_by': userId},
                    {'list.user_id': userId}
                ]
            }
        ],
        deleted: false
    };
    // Fire the request to find an object based on the above queryParams
    ModelObject.findOne(queryParams....
```

The question is, what is the best index configuration to use here, the collection is all in one. 
Is it a matter of creating a group index by the above fields? _id is already indexed, can this be re-used here!!! Does the $and and $or have any impact?

```
modelSchema.index({'_id': 1, 'stats.created_by': 1, 'list.user_id': 1, 'deleted': 1});
```

Any advice, best practice would be appreciated here.

Thanks.

J

Comment: `_id` is a unique field which makes any of the other query parameters completely redundant. Once `_id` is matched then it's all over. That field is indexed by default always.

Comment: I understand that _id is auto indexed but how does it play a role in the above scenario when used inconjunction with other fields and set operators.

Comment: The Role it plays is since there is only one document with the `_id` value of 1 then searching for `{ _id: 1, something: "else" }` is redundant because `_id: ` already identified the document. The only case is if the "something" field does not contain "else". But that's just testing the value of the single document retrieved. There is no additional index that helps that. Only 1 document is matched in index, then the other conditions are tested to the match. Understand now?

Comment: @user3561036 appreciate your insight, so the match is on _id, the subsequent fields are redundant and so only used for testing purposes on the returned document. Thanks.